# How to setup VMWare Workstation proxy so I can connect Linux CentOS to the internet

Tags: linux, proxy, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I have a VMWare Workstation and I installed Linux CentOS on it and it doesnt connect to the internet. How can I make the setting for the VMWare Workstation so it connects to the internet thru the proxy ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you configured the VM network as NAT, Bridged or Host-only?

Comment: If you use bridged networking, you'll need to configure the network settings in the guest in a similar way you configured the network settings on the host.  Or just use NAT and it should work automatically.